# What are the form of the inputs into the BERT NLP model?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

After having read the BERT paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805), I am still slightly confused as to what for the input (words) take.

They refer to a paper which essentially tokenize words, but do not explicitly show what it looks like.

Thanks for the clarification.

Tom

Answer (score 1):

It'd be better if you see the real examples provided in [BERT's official Github repo](https://github.com/google-research/bert).
The section [tokenization](https://github.com/google-research/bert#tokenization) might be able to give you a better understanding of how it actually works.